# Definition of infinite tree in set theory

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Really basic question concerning trees in set theory.

*What is the definition of an **infinite** tree?*

I ask the following because, rather peculiarly, neither in Kechris classical book on descriptive set theory, nor in Srivastava book on the same topic, there is an explicit definition, even if they both use the concept (e.g. Srivastava use the infinity of a tree for the Koenig's infinity lemma, p.28).

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit after the answers:**
Thanks all for the number of answers, and the quality behind them.

Comment: Off the top of my head I would imagine there are a few definitions. E.g. are you looking for countable or uncountalbe, infinite branching or finite branching...

Comment: Well, that's the puzzling part. That's what you can find on Srivastava: *"**Proposition 1.10.7** (Koenig’s infinity lemma) Let T be a finitely splitting, infinite tree on A. Then T is ill-founded."* So here, there is my problem, I would like to know how to read the "infinite" over there.

Comment: My copy of Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory contains a whole chapter on trees and defines them on page 5.

Comment: @Stefan: Could you point out to me the exact sentence in which he explicitly defines **infinite trees**? At p.5 I can only see the definitions of **infinite concatenation** and **infinite branch** (with the word "infinite").

Comment: @Kolmin Sure, in Definition 2.1 he writes "A **tree** on a set $A$ is a subset $T \subseteq A^{< \mathbb N}$ closed under initial segments [..]". You highlighted **infinite** in your question and if this is the point of your question: infinite just means that $T$ is infinite as a set. Also note that Asaf's definition is a generalization of this notion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Enlightening comment, and nice way to realise I thought I have read, but I did not really do it (common situation – for me – in math).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that a tree is a partial order that for each point $x$, the cone below $x$ is well-ordered.

An infinite tree is a tree with infinitely many nodes.

Sometimes, however it is easier to work with "reversed" trees. With reversed ordering, being well-founded is equivalent to not having an infinite branch. And that is something which comes up often in descriptive set theory.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, in set theory language, a (possibly infinite) "tree" means a nonempty set of sequences of symbols (for example integers), which is closed under taking prefixes.

What does this have to do with the graph-theoretic concept of a tree? Assume that you're labeling all edges in the tree with a symbol such that no node has two *outgoing* edges with the same label. The set theorists' representation of the tree then consists of an "address" of each node in the tree, where the address is the sequence of edge labels on the (unique) path from the root to the node in question.

The root node is addressed by the empty sequence.

The complete binary tree with 7 nodes would be
$$ \{(), (0), (0,0), (0,1), (1), (1,0), (1,1) \} $$
and an infinite unary tree would be
$$ \{(), (0), (0,0), (0,0,0), \ldots \} $$

The tree is infinite if it has inifinitely many nodes.

Additional constraints on the tree can be defined, such as each node must have finitely many successors, or that there's a *global* finite limit on the number of successors to a node.

---

As Asaf points out, it is sometimes useful to allow transfinitely long (but still well-ordered) sequences as addresses. This gives rise to trees that don't correspond directly to graph-theoretic trees (because nodes whose address is indexed by a limit ordinal won't have immediate parents).

Comment: Finite sequences? How can an Aronszajn tree or a Suslin tree be defined like that?

Comment: @Asaf: Hmm, perhaps this concept is too restrictive.

Comment: What about cycles? Does your definition exclude them? I would say a tree must be strictly acyclic

Comment: @ColmBhandal: How would cycles even be representable in this way? Every node that can be reached from another node has a strictly longer address, so a cycle would need an address that is longer than itself!

Comment: In set theory a tree is a partial order $( T , \leq )$ where for each $t \in T$ the set $\{ x \in T : x \leq t \}$ is well-ordered by $\leq$. In _descriptive set-theory_ this is restricted to subsets of $A^{< \omega}$ closed under initial segments, with some caveats when dealing with "product trees".

Comment: @HenningMakholm ignore my comment, ten minutes later I can't figure out what I was talking about.

Answer (score 3):

As asked, you actually need to specify a little bit more to be precise. I'll first assume you're asking about infinite, *binary branching* trees. A *binary branching tree* $T$ is a collection of finite strings of zeros and ones, called nodes, such that, whenever a string $\sigma$ is in $T$, all of its prefixes are in $T$. An *infinite* binary branching tree is a binary branching tree with infinitely many strings in it (each individual string is finite).

More generally, you can talk about trees branching on an arbitrary set $A$. Then, rather than considering (sets of) strings of zeros and ones, you consider (sets of) strings of elements of $A$. The definition of an *infinite* tree is the same: a tree containing infinitely many strings.